# I have "a limited space" vs. I have "limited space"

Tags: grammar

The Corpus of Contemporary American English (https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) shows both.

I have a small room so I have _____________________.

(1) a limited space.
(2) limited space.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both are.  Space can be used as either a countable or an uncountable noun.  Context is everything.

> I have a small room so I have limited space... for storing all my junk.
>
> I have a small room so I have a limited space... for really creative decorating.

Oxford defines it as countable and uncountable.
http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/space_1

Comment: However it would be wrong to say "I have two small rooms so I have a limited space".

Answer (score 0):

*Space* is basically uncountable (see  [this dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/space_1)), thus mainly (2) in that context.

It can work as uncountable in circumstances where **a certain area is dedicated to a purpose**

> The Kindergarten-primary Magazine - Volume 45 - Page 124 Bertha
>   Johnston, ‎E. Lyell Earle - 1932
>
> For most schools, however, which close in June, and have **a limited
>   space for their gardens**, the best vegetables to plant are radishes,
>   beans, lettuce, chard and spinach.

but that usage is 10x less frequent at Google Books.